# Deleting Parentheses in Output

Tags: python, regex

I used `f.write(str(ints))` to write this output to a text file. How can I delete the parentheses in

```
(0, 212, 262)
```

I have tried to use regex, but it says a string or bytes object is required when I input the following:

```
re.search('\((.*?)\)', ints)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
In the given code, `ints` is undefined.  Is it a list of integers?

Comment: Or, even better, `str(ints)[1:-1]`

Comment: If so, the problem is that you're trying to remove parenthesis characters from a data structure -- the parentheses exist only in the output image.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Wow! So Simple! Thank you-I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that without regex like this:

```
>>> ints = (0, 212, 262)
>>> str(ints)[1:-1]
'0, 212, 262'
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It didn't do that on my end, so he might have just copied it wrong

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have a better idea: don't put the parentheses in the output in the first place.  Put the `str` images of the integers into a list, then `join` them as desired:

```
ints = (0, 212, 262)
# Improvement per ettanany
output = ', '.join(str(item) for item in ints)
print output
```

Output:

```
0, 212, 262
```

Alternate way of converting to str, per COLDSPEED

```
output = ', '.join(map(str, ints))
```

Comment: Or just, `', '.join(map(str, ints))`

Comment: You do not need to use list in your case, a generator expression is more efficient `', '.join(str(item) for item in ints)`

Comment: @ettanany Or my comment just above :p

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ True, that's a good option! I mean just instead of using list, a generator expression can be used here and it's recommended, especially for large lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val = (0, 212, 262)
print(str(val).strip('(').strip(')')) # >> 0, 212, 262
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to pass a tuple to the RegEx.
Try `str(ints).strip("(").strip(")")`.

Comment: That makes sense! This was my first time experimenting with RegEx, so that is good to know : )